# Ubuntu 18.04 Server with FluxBox X and python app

Tags: 18.04, python, xorg, fluxbox, kivy

I have been trying to run my .py file using ubuntu server and fluxbox. 
I wanted to make that my file will run after fluxbox minimal desktop starts.

But when i edit ~/.fluxbox/startup file, the X automatically exits without any error.

My **.fluxbox/startup** file looks like:

```
...
exec fluxbox & /home/user/KivyProject/run
...
```

when i delete **/home/user/KivyProject/run** fluxbox works normally.

My **run** script looks like:

```
python /home/user/KivyProject/main.py
```

my .py file looks like:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')
TestApp().run()
```

What am i doing wrong? Where should i put the path to my script in order to run it after X starts?

Thanks in advance for every reply!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `exec fluxbox` should be the last line in the startup file. 
Maybe try changing it to:

```
 ...
 /home/user/KivyProject/run & 
 exec fluxbox
```

Comment: For diagnostic purposes perhaps modify to: `exec fluxbox -log "/home/user/.fluxbox/log" `